# Prompting and Delegate question

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, delegates

I have a class that needs to ask the user a question and wait for the users response to determine the next action. What would be the best way to do this? Using a delegate? How? I have a UITextField and a UITextField in the class.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends upon how you wish for the user to submit the data. The most user friendly way is to do as TahoeWolverine explained and implement `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` from `UITextFieldDelegate`. In order to use this, the class that implements `textFieldShouldReturn:` must have `<UITextFieldDelegate>` protocol in its interface declaration; moreover, the textfield in question must have the `UITextFieldDelegate`-implementing class set as its delegate. In most cases those would look like this:

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    UITextField *myField;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *myfield
@end
```

and somewhere in the implementation:

```
[[self myField] setDelegate:self];
```

Finally, implementing the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == [self myField]) {
         [self doSomethingWithText:[[self myField] text]];
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yep, I've actually used textFieldShouldReturn in another app, great suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use a delegate, and link that to the keyboard's done button (I'm assuming that you're presenting the user a keyboard). Simply link your delegate to the return key of the keyboard, and that should do the trick.